# BeanPropertySqlParameterSource with pojo annotations

Tags: java, spring, jdbctemplate

I have the following

```
@Data //Lombok annotation to generate getters and setters
@Entity
public class TradeLog {
    @Id
    @Column(name="P_TRADE_ID")
    private String tradeId;
}

tradeLog.setTradeId("1");
SqlParameterSource insertParam = new BeanPropertySqlParameterSource(tradeLog);
    System.out.println(insertProc.execute(insertParam));
```

And I get this error `Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Required input parameter 'P_TRADE_ID' is missing`

I know that I could do a mapping directly on the jdbc template, but is there any way I could use the java persistence annotations or something like that to handle that for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JDBC template does not provide such thing, But you can easily use reflection to scan all the `@Column` fields and populate its value to `MapSqlParameterSource` which is another implementation of `SqlParameterSource`. Something like below , you can wrap it to a function for convenient :

```
tradeLog.setTradeId("1");

//Create MapSqlParameterSource based on tradeLog
MapSqlParameterSource param = new MapSqlParameterSource();
for(Field field :  TradeLog.class.getDeclaredFields()) {
    Column column =   field.getAnnotation(Column.class);

    if(column != null) {
        field.setAccessible(true);
        param.addValue(column.name(), field.get(tradeLog));     
    }
}

insertProc.execute(param)
```

Comment: That's a bummer. Probably better to give my fields gross names than use reflection, but thanks for confirming that what I wanted didn't exist.